# Remove a script from a template file using wp_dequeue_script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I thought I had read it was possible to use `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_dequeue_script()` directly in  individual template files. However, when I add

```
  wp_dequeue_script( 'myscript' );
```

to the top of page.php, `myscript` still gets loaded.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 9):

Script dequeuing calls should be added to the `wp_print_scripts` action hook, like so:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','example_dequeue_myscript');
function example_dequeue_myscript() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'myscript' );
}
```

This is because scripts are typically enqueued on the wp_enqueue_script hook, which happens early in the wp_head process. The wp_print_scripts hook happens right before scripts are printed, and thus is latest in the process.

Comment: So is it not possible to use `wp_dequeue_script` directly in a template file?

Comment: It's possible, but the effectiveness of it will be determined by how the plugin/theme enqueues the script. The method I give should work in the majority of cases.

Comment: Thanks, works fine for child themes and also for stylesheets. (action: wp_print_styles and function: wp_dequeue_style)